# How can I add an hour on to the time set but the SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, simpledateformat

I have a start button with the current time displaying and I want to be able to have a button with a stop time that is an hour later than the current time. How can I go about doing this?

Here is my code for the button displaying the current time

```
Button stopButton = (Button) this
            .findViewById(R.id.StartTrackingEditStopTime_button);
    // using SimpleDateFormat class
    SimpleDateFormat sdfStopTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a",
            Locale.ENGLISH);
    String newStoptime = sdfStopTime
            .format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

    stopButton.append(newStoptime);
```

Many thanks for any help or advice on how to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way you are setting a time with `new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())` currently is taking the exact, current millisecond and making a date out of it. If you insist on working with milliseconds, what you need to do is add an hour's worth of milliseconds or 1000 * 60 * 60 = 3600000.

Thus, **Way #1** you can fulfill your needs is with this exact code:

```
Button stopButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StartTrackingEditStopTime_button);

SimpleDateFormat sdfStopTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);

String newStoptime = sdfStopTime.format(
        new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 3600000));

stopButton.setText(newStopTime);
```

This will work. **Way #2** to accomplish this, and useful if you're systematically working with times, is to use the Calendar object. To do this, replace the third line from above with the following code:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
Date d = c.getTime();
String newStopTime = sdfStopTime.format(d);
```

Hope this helps! Your choice.

Comment: Thanks Bepetersn, I have got the Way#1 to work fine but with Way#2 I have a problem on the line `Date d = c.getTime();` I get the error Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.Date to java.sql.Date. Could you please help

Comment: I found changing the above line to this worked. Is this a good approach? `java.util.Date d = c.getTime();`

Comment: Hey, I had a pretty egregious error in my original answer that I just noticed, in Way #1, which was that I had you changing the time by a whole day, where you had asked to change it for an hour. I just fixed that. 

As for Way #2, I was less certain about that one. I haven't tried that one myself, but from what I can see in the documentation, that's what it should be.

Comment: Thanks for fixing this up. I also noticed that but didn't mention anything as i figured it out. I also noticed that your declaration of newStopTime has different case lettering which causes errors, so you can edit that also. Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 2):

This keeps everything in SimpleDateFormat. No need to create extra objects.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdfStopTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a", Locale.ENGLISH);

System.out.println("Before: " + sdfStopTime.getCalendar().getTime());

sdfStopTime.getCalendar().add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);

System.out.println("After: " + sdfStopTime.getCalendar().getTime());
```

The first argument of the add() method is the field, hours, minutes etc.
The second argument is the amount you want to add, if negative you substract.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, Is this how I am sposed to place this in my code as it does not seem to make any changes.  `Button stopButton = (Button) this.findViewById R.id.StartTrackingEditStopTime_button);
SimpleDateFormat sdfStopTime = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a",Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println("Before: " + sdfStopTime.getCalendar().getTime());
sdfStopTime.getCalendar().add(Calendar.HOUR, 10);
System.out.println("After: " + sdfStopTime.getCalendar().getTime());
String newStoptime = sdfStopTime.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
stopButton.append(newStoptime);

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Calendar` class ([javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html)). Assuming that you already have a `Date now`:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(now);
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
Date inAnHour = calendar.getTime();

// format inAnHour with your DateFormat and set a button label
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add one hour to the current time.

```
// You don't have to put System.currentTimeMillis() to the constructor.
// Default constructor of Date gives you the current time.
Date stopTime = new Date();
stopTime.setHours(stopTime.getHours() + 1);
String newStoptime = sdfStopTime.format(stopTime);
stopButton.append(newStoptime);
```

If you don't want to use deprecated functions `setHours` and `getHours`,
use `setTime` and `getTime` and add 3,600,000 milli seconds (1 hour) to the current time:

```
stopTime.setTime(stopTime.getTime() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

instead of

```
stopTime.setHours(stopTime.getHours() + 1);
```

Comment: Hi Heejin, on the following line `stopTime.setHours(stopTime.getHours() + 1);` I have the following warning which make the application force close Multiple markers at this line
 - The method getHours() from the type Date is 
  deprecated
 - The method setHours(int) from the type Date is 
  deprecated

Comment: @WillNZ I added more to my answer that using other functions instead of deprecated ones.

Comment: You make unnececary calculations and you create 2 unneeded objects.